# What book did The Emperor speak with The Ultramatrine Primarch?

Tags: warhammer-40k

After finishing Dark Imperium: Plague Wars i found out that Robute spoke to the Emperor at some point after coming out of stasis.

Has this happened in any book or is this just something that has not yet been penned??

Comment: It may have been in one of the "Gathering of the Storm" books that went alongside the 8th Edition. My understanding is that they're mission/rulebooks like the Horus Heresy rulebooks, but have a lot of "fluff" regarding Guilliman's reawakening and whatnot.

Comment: If I remember right, in the "Dark Imperium" Roboute said that "talking with his father was like talking with a star". So the conversation might be on a totally different level than simple words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**

- Currently, there is nothing.
- I highly doubt there will ever be anything.

So, there are no actual descriptions of the meeting Guilliman took with the Emperor. Further, there is nothing that we really know of regarding this meeting other than what Guilliman mentions while speaking to others or reflecting on his own.

In the initial novel Dark Imperium there is one or two times where Guilliman mentions to someone he is speaking to that he has sworn never to reveal what occurred inside the Throne Room; mind you I do not remember who he was talking to or where the passage(s) were in the book.

Similar to how we don't know a lot of the other details in the 40k verse, like the Emperor's true name, I would suspect we will never learn what was actually said between them. That would open Pandora's box for GW to actually come up with questions between the two and the secrecy of it all is much easier for GW to build a story around.

On a side note: The only relating event, that I have recently learned of, that may be of interest to you I believe is from the newest rulebook and/or the novel Watchers of the Throne: The Emperor's Legion.

Similar to how in 801.M41 the Astronomicon flickered and all those ships were lost, I heard that at some point after the Great Rift and Guilliman was revived it happened again. I am unsure of when it happened, but this was supposed to have been a more extended event that occurred. It may have been around the time that Guilliman spoke to his Father which would be very interesting.

I do not remember reading this event from the rulebook after I got it, and I have not had a chance to look up this detail yet, but I am curious if it is true.

This is the only instance I was able to find online from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/40kLore/comments/bg3nrb/astronomican_is_failing/):

"...Watchers of the Throne: The Emperor's Legion has a lot of context.

"The astronomican going out was a recent event and occured when the Great Rift opened up:

"‘Our star-dreamers, those who live still, tell me this is only the beginning,’ Italeo went on. ‘The Eye is growing. Space around it is tearing. We have lost contact with large regions of His realm beyond a growing chasm of darkness. And amid all of this, and most grave, the Astronomican has failed.’

"(Tribune Italeo of the Adeptus Custodes, briefing his fellow Custodes in the muster chamber.)

"According to Tieron, Chancellor of the High Council of Terra, after it flickered back on they weren't and still aren't exactly certain why it failed or what restored it:

"I never discovered the cause of the Astronomican’s failure, nor understood the means by which it was eventually restored. It may be that Raskian had been able to resolve some mechanical problem, either in the Throne itself or the mighty conduits that linked it to the fortress, though he never claimed credit for it if he had. The resumption of the beacon **may have had something to do with Guilliman’s sojourn in the Throneroom**, although he also never spoke about what he had seen or done in there, at least with me, so that whole episode must remain pure conjecture.

"As for the Golden Throne, that hasn't failed yet but I believe it's been described as being in a bad shape for a while in the lore. The problem is that it cannot be switched off or allowed to fail even for a moment and so 10,000 years worth of repairs have turned it into an ever-growing patchwork mechanical nightmare. Heracleon, Tribune who stands guard over the Emperor himself along with the rest of the Hetaeron Guard, says as much:

"‘If they are true visions. But the Throne is not what it was.’

"Even as he spoke, I saw a hiss of steam burst from an overhead coolant line, high up in the tangled heights. Immediately a little skull-drone swept up towards it, isolating the leak and hovering below it, dendrites flickering.

"‘As you see,’ Heracleon remarked, dryly. ‘Come, this way.’

"So the astronomican failing was situational and tied into the beginning of the Great Rift, but the Golden Throne issues preceded it and have been an ongoing problem for a lot longer: since 989.M36 many more psykers have been needed to keep it fed and in very late m41 some terrifying mechanical failures were discovered..."

Comment: a realy good answer. i was hoping that there were some morsels in the carrion throne or the gathering storm... but alas... GW did it again.

Comment: Haha... just gotta be patient!